# C# DataTable, get value by Row/Column index

Tags: c#, indexing, data-structures, datatable

I have a `DataTable` which is populated by a csv file, with 8 columns and approximately 2000 rows. I wish to populate an object with my csv values that are currently stored in my `DataTable`

How do I index a specific `DataTable` cell? In other words, I wish to treat the data table in a similar way you would a 2D array, like so:

`string value = array[i][j];`

Here is my code:

```
DataTable d = GetDataTableFromCSVFile(file);
for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < d.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
         //string x = d[i][j]; <-- something like this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @codersl, I've had a look through some examples on here but I must've missed that one, ill take a look

Answer (score 12, accepted):

like this

```
string x = d.Rows[i][j].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to iterate the `DataTable`. 
`Foreach` works faster then `for` loop:

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dtTable.Columns)
    {
      var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each loop to get your data.

```
            string x = string.Empty;
            DataTable d = FileHelpers.CommonEngine.CsvToDataTable(@"D:\Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv", "Sacramentorealestatetransactions", ',', true); // Get FileHelpers package from NuGet
            foreach(DataRow row in d.Rows)
                foreach (object dc in row.ItemArray)
                    x = dc.ToString();
```